# How to calculate the gradients of an image?

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

The following code allows to calculate the gradients of an image using the Sobel operators, that are available in OpenCV.

```
IplImage* grad_x = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image),IPL_DEPTH_32F,1);
IplImage* grad_y = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image),IPL_DEPTH_32F,1);
cvSobel(image,grad_x,1,0,3);
cvSobel(image,grad_y,0,1,3);
```

How are the edges handled by the `cvSobel()` function? What is the difference between this function and <del>[this one](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=sobel)</del> [this one](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#sobel)? I read about available `borderType` options, however, I do not know which of these options would be better to use.

Moreover, what advantages could provide performing a smoothing filter before calculating the gradients of an image?

Finally, after calculating the gradients of an image, how to calculate the corresponding angles and magnitude?

Comment: The gradient is just the point-wise arctangent between these derivates the magical `cvSobel` functions gave you. The magnitude is the square root of the sum of these magical squared returns. A small amount of smoothing is good because natural images are always noisy. I don't know what function you are pointing out, so I don't know what difference you could be talking about. This is all basic stuff in edge detection, any good book on this will give a lot more of information and how to derive different edge detectors.

Comment: @mmgp: I wanted to point out [this function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#sobel).

Comment: Click this exact link you included and you will see the trouble I'm having.

Comment: @mmgp: What do you mean by "you will see the trouble I'm having"?

Comment: Now I clicked at it again and now I landed on a Sobel function, earlier it didn't work like that. But you are using that function already, I don't know what you are asking then in regard of "difference between the functions". Clarify that such that you don't need to include a link.

Comment: The `Sobel` function has more parameters that the [`cvSobel`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/image_filtering.html#sobel) function, for example the `borderType`. If I were to add an border (with a thickness of one pixel) to the image before calculating the gradients, the addition of a border could result in edges that are not present in the original image, so what kind of `borderType` should I use to avoid this? In other words, given the original image and their gradients, what type of border should I add in order to obtain the same values for the gradients?

Comment: many image processing algorithms have edge cases when it comes to the border of your image. Suppose you don't specific a `borderType` (or equivalent) parameter anywhere, then the function assumes some default behavior. This default behavior could be, for example, do not process the borders, or when handling the border consider only the points inside the image, or consider some value for points outside the image. So to obtain the same results you have to specify a border such that it matches the behavior of the other function that doesn't take a `borderType` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in edge maps, you should consider the [Canny](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=canny#void%20Canny%28InputArray%20image,%20OutputArray%20edges,%20double%20threshold1,%20double%20threshold2,%20int%20apertureSize,%20bool%20L2gradient%29) method in OpenCV. `Sobel` will return a gradient image, which you can then derive the edge map from via simple thresholding using [threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#double%20threshold%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20double%20thresh,%20double%20maxval,%20int%20type%29), or you can do something more complex like the `Canny` method.

Smoothing the image (e.g., via [GaussianBlur](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=gaussian#void%20GaussianBlur%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20Size%20ksize,%20double%20sigmaX,%20double%20sigmaY,%20int%20borderType%29) or [blur](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=blur#void%20blur%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20Size%20ksize,%20Point%20anchor,%20int%20borderType%29)) will reduce the magnified noise levels which result from the `Sobel` operation.

I have a very similar answer located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11157426/951860), which shows how determine the magnitude and phase of the gradients.

Hope that helps!