# How to detect image gradient or normal using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, ellipse

I wanted to detect ellipse in an image. Since I was learning Mathematica at that time, I asked a question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25589/how-can-i-detect-an-ellipse-in-a-photo) and got a satisfactory result from the answer below, which used the RANSAC algorithm to detect ellipse.

However, recently I need to port it to OpenCV, but there are some functions that only exist in Mathematica. One of the key function is the "GradientOrientationFilter" function.

Since there are five parameters for a general ellipse, I need to sample five points to determine one. Howevere, the more sampling points indicates the lower chance to have a good guess, which leads to the lower success rate in ellipse detection. Therefore, the answer from Mathematica add another condition, that is the gradient of the image must be parallel to the gradient of the ellipse equation. Anyway, we'll only need three points to determine one ellipse using least square from the Mathematica approach. The result is quite good.

However, when I try to find the image gradient using Sobel or Scharr operator in OpenCV, it is not good enough, which always leads to the bad result.

How to calculate the gradient or the tangent of an image accurately? Thanks!

---

Result with gradient, three points
[image: Result with gradient, three points]

Result without gradient, five points
[image: Result without gradient, five points]

----------updated----------

I did some edge detect and median blur beforehand and draw the result on the edge image. My original test image is like this:

[image: original test image]

In general, my final goal is to detect the ellipse in a scene or on an object. Something like this:

[image: coffee cup]

That's why I choose to use RANSAC to fit the ellipse from edge points.

Comment: "Since there are five parameters for a general ellipse, I need to sample five points to determine one." > I would be interested to have a detailed explanation on this, because for me 3 _two-dimensional_ points are enough to estimate 5 _scalar_ parameters. About your question, can you include in your question the code you used to estimate the gradient?

Comment: My idea is that a general ellipse would be ax^2+by^2+cxy+dx+ey+1=0. So if I want to solve this equation, I need to have five point, (x1,y1)~(x5,y5). Substitute them into the (x,y) of the ellipse equation, I can solve the simultaneous equations of five variables. That's why I say I need to sample five points to determine one.

Comment: The code snippet is [here](http://notepad.cc/mafugo39)

Comment: Considering the updated image, use the generalized Hough transform.

Answer (score 2):

As for your final goal, you may try

**[findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html)** and **[[fitEllipse]](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rotated_ellipses/bounding_rotated_ellipses.html)** in OpenCV

The pseudo code will be

1) some image process

2) find all contours

3) fit each contours by fitEllipse

here is part of code I use before

```
[... image process ....you get a bwimage ]

vector<vector<Point> > contours;
findContours(bwimage, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);


for(size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    size_t count = contours[i].size();

    Mat pointsf;
    Mat(contours[i]).convertTo(pointsf, CV_32F);
    RotatedRect box = fitEllipse(pointsf);

    /* You can put some limitation about size and aspect ratio here */
    if( box.size.width > 20 && 
        box.size.height > 20 && 
        box.size.width < 80 && 
        box.size.height < 80 )
    {
    if( MAX(box.size.width, box.size.height) > MIN(box.size.width, box.size.height)*30 )
        continue;
    //drawContours(SrcImage, contours, (int)i, Scalar::all(255), 1, 8);

    ellipse(SrcImage, box, Scalar(0,0,255), 1, CV_AA);
    ellipse(SrcImage, box.center, box.size*0.5f, box.angle, 0, 360, Scalar(200,255,255), 1, CV_AA);
    }
}

imshow("result", SrcImage);
```

---

Comment: This looks good! But how can I judge whether the ellipse I detected is good enough? For example, from my original RANSAC method, I can use the number of points that is close to the ellipse as a criteria. The more points the better. In the method you proposed, how to rank the detected ellipse? Thanks!

Comment: I want to vote up this answer but I don't have enough reputation to do so......sorry about that.

Comment: Since you pass each contour you found to fitellipse() which means all independent objects after image processing will be fitted. The vector<Point> is all points of a SINGLE contour (vector of vector<Point> is an array/collection of contour, that's why named contourS). So you have the fitted ellipse and the original points of each contour. In principle, you can apply some criteria.

Comment: So you may use the size(number of points) of EACH contour to filter too small/large object. The ratio of moment of inertia Ixx/Iyy of EACH contour to filter line segment. fitellipse() is very expensive in computation time.
About the vote, I don't come for that, so that is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you focus on ellipse(no other shape), you can treat the value of the pixels of the ellipse as mass of the points.

Then you can calculate the moment of inertial Ixx, Iyy, Ixy to find out the angle, theta, which can rotate a general ellipse back to a canonical form (X-Xc)^2/a + (Y-Yc)^2/b = 1.

Then you can find out Xc and Yc by the center of mass.

Then you can find out a and b by min X and min Y.

--------------- update -----------

This method can apply to filled ellipse too.

More than one ellipse on a single image will fail unless you segment them first.

Let me explain more,
I will use C to represent cos(theta) and S to represent sin(theta)

After rotation to canonical form, the new X is [eq0] X=xC-yS and Y is Y=xS+yC where x and y are original positions.

The rotation will give you min IYY.

[eq1]

IYY= Sum(m*Y*Y) = Sum{m*(xS+yC)*(xS+yC)} = Sum{ m*(xxSS+yyCC+xySC) = Ixx*S^2 + Iyy*C^2 + Ixy*S*C

For min IYY, d(IYY)/d(theta) = 0 that is

2IxxSC - 2IyySC + Ixy(CC-SS) = 0

2(Ixx-Iyy)/Ixy = (SS-CC)/SC = S/C+C/S = Z+1/Z

While programming, the LHS is just a number, let's said N

Z^2 - NZ +1 =0

So there are two roots of Z hence theta, let's said Z1 and Z2, one will min the IYY and the other will max the IYY.

----------- pseudo code --------

Compute Ixx, Iyy, Ixy for a hollow or filled ellipse.

Compute theta1=atan(Z1) and theta2=atan(Z2)

Put These two theta into eq1 find which is smaller. Then you get theta.

Go back to those non-zero pixels, transfer them to new X and Y by the theta you found.

Find center of mass Xc Yc and min X and min Y by sort().

-------------- by hand -----------

If you need the original equation of the ellipse

Just put [eq0] into the canonical form

Comment: You can fairly easily find the major axis: pick two random points on the edge, and see if you can increase the distance between them by alternately moving either point along the edge. The major axis is unique in that it maximizes the distance between the two points, and the function is continuous. Good starting point candidates are the two extremes in either X or Y direction. Breaks down somewhat for small, round ellipses due to rounding of pixel coordinates. You can also easily determine the circumference.  Another approach is just a direct Least Squares on the 6 parameters.

Comment: I've updated the original post for this. Sorry for the ambiguous description before. Since I want to detect an ellipse in a rather complicated scene or on an object, there are points that is not belong to the ellipse. That's why I use RANSAC to detect an ellipse, rather than fit an ellipse.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! This method seems to be quite goo for an image that only contain one ellipse. However, for my application there are usually one ellipse and other lines rectangles and etc. But still thanks for your reply:)

Answer (score 0):

You're using terms in an unusual way.

Normally for **images**, the term "gradient" is interpreted as if the image is a mathematical function `f(x,y)`. This gives us a `(df/dx, df/dy)` vector in each point.

Yet you're looking at the image as if it's a function `y = f(x)` and the gradient would be `f(x)/dx`.

Now, if you look at your image, you'll see that the two interpretations are definitely related. Your ellipse is drawn as a set of contrasting pixels, and as a result there are **two** sharp gradients in the image - the inner and outer. These of course correspond to the two normal vectors, and therefore are in opposite directions.

Also note that your image has pixels. The gradient is also pixelated. The way your ellipse is drawn, with a single pixel width means that your local gradient takes on only values that are a multiple of 45 degrees:

```
▄▄ ▄▀ ▌ ▀▄
```

Comment: The Image gradient I mean here is, as your first case, (df/dx, df/dy) vector in each point.

Comment: I've updated my original post. My original test image is a solid ellipse. And I do edge detect to get the edge points. But the gradient is calculated using the solid ellipse. Except for all this, since I only want the direction of the gradient, so the inner gradient vector and the outer gradient vector are still parallel and should still be the normal vector, is that right?

Comment: Since I calculated the image gradient orientation on each pixel using dx and dy from Sobel operator, will that still be quantized into 45, 90,135... degrees?

Comment: @AlbertK: No, Sobel smooths that gradient using a 3x3 kernel.

Comment: This seems to be contradictory to the answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815732/what-is-gradient-orientation-and-gradient-magnitude), which is the procedure I followed to calculate the gradient orientation:
    1.Compute Sobel in the X direction (Sx).
    2.Compute Sobel in the Y direction (Sy).
    3.Compute the gradient orientation with arctan(Sy / Sx).

Comment: @AlbertK: Doesn't seem like a contradiction to me. Since the values Sx and Sy are smoothed, they can take on more values (anything between -4 and +4) so arctan(Sy/Sx) can take on quite a few more values, too.